# Mysql resetted after upgrading from 80025 to 80027

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, upgrade

I was with `8.0.25-0ubuntu0.20.04.1` (as the log say), and I made `apt update && apt upgrade` (specially to fix some issue with other packages).

But, when upgrading, it said "Failed to upgrade mysql and mysql-server". So, I was thinking everything was back as before trying to upgrade. It failed, apparently because I didn't have enough space on disk. Now, I have enough one.

Actually, I'm with `8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1`, and the database doesn't have any password, any content ...

I change the password. Then, I tried to login into it, but phpMyAdmin or even all other programs failed to log in (but I can with command line). I change the bind-address to `0.0.0.0`, even if the connection that I'm testing is in local

Some logs that can help you :

```
[System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
[Warning] [MY-012638] [InnoDB] Retry attempts for writing partial data failed.
[ERROR] [MY-012639] [InnoDB] Write to file ./ibtmp1 failed at offset 0, 1048576 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written. Operating system error number 28. Check that your OS and file system support files of this size. Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
[ERROR] [MY-012640] [InnoDB] Error number 28 means 'No space left on device'
[ERROR] [MY-012267] [InnoDB] Could not set the file size of './ibtmp1'. Probably out of disk space
```

I searched some way, but post are asking how to upgrading, and so people are making dump. But even with old data dump, I don't have the full configuration or the mysql server. (Also, lot of post are talking about upgrading from 5.X to 8.X, me it's between 8.0.25 to 8.0.27...)

How can I go back to old mysql config? And get back data?

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. You should have a backup of your database. Reinstall your server, then mysql and then restore the backup from your secure location. You do have a backup, right?

Comment: In fact, I have a backup because the server is replicated. But I don't have a full mysql backup with config, or even simply a dump of this exact server

Comment: Perhaps it was installed in a different place?  And maybe the old data is still there?

Comment: @RickJames Maybe, but I'm not sure there is the full data. And I was looking for some quick backup made before the upgrade. Maybe it's just a different folder, I don't know what change between both. And mostly, it's all config changes that I want to get back, I don't want to work on it during one week ...